# Hover effect on MouseOver using CSS on image

Tags: css, animation

Want a hover effect on project section of the portfolio.

The layout is made up of CSS Grid and On Hover the link to view Live Demo should appear responsive. Animation transition

Tried but  the hover effect  but messed up the layout.

**It must be using css hover animation only** and **NO Javascript.**

The hover effect to show the link .

@DylanScript gave the solution but not working porperly. Attached image
[image]

Second image for reference
[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.projects {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.7rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.projects img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px #fff solid;
}

.projects img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.infobar {
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30%;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background: #413a44;
}

.infobar p {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover .infobar {
  bottom: 0%;
}

.viewBar:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.viewBar img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  transition: .32s ease-in-out;
}

.viewBar:hover img {
  bottom: 30%;
}

.item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.01);
  filter: grayscale(0.6);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1171px) {
  .projects {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1170px) {
  .projects {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>

</nav>
<main>
  <div class="projects">
    <div class="item viewBar">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x899/?water">
      </a>
      <div class="infobar">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          <a href="#" class="btn-light">
                            Demo...
                        </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item viewBar">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x899/?water">
      </a>
      <div class="infobar">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          <a href="#" class="btn-light">
                            Demo...
                        </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item viewBar">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x899/?water">
      </a>
      <div class="infobar">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          <a href="#" class="btn-light">
                            Demo...
                        </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</main>

<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: I think your problem is that once you hover over the item the image get's pushed up and you are not hovering the item. That means the image get's pushed down, resulting in hovering again and the image getting pushed up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `position: absolute` on img and .infobar, by applying `position: relative` the animations perform correctly:

```
.viewBar img {
  position: relative; ##########
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  transition: .32s ease-in-out;
}

.infobar {
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  position: relative; ###########
  bottom: -30%;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background: #413a44;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @ DylanScript Thanks For Solution But It does not work porperly.
 hover over the item the image get's pushed up

Answer (score 0):

Your `position` and `margin-bottom` are the ones causing the problem.

update

```
.infobar {
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background: #413a44;
}

.viewBar img {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .32s ease-in-out;
}
```

remove

```
.viewBar:hover img {
  bottom: 30%;
}
```

**UPDATED**

set your `.item` position to `relative`

```
.item{
    position: relative;
}
```

then `.infobar` position to `absolute`. I also changed the `height` `margin-bottom` `padding` in order to achieve your desired effect

```
.infobar {
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  /* updates */  
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  /* end updates */  
  transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
  background: #413a44;
}
```

Then on `.item:hover`

```
.item:hover .infobar {
  height: 30%;
}
```

change the `transition` duration on the `p` to `.3s` same as the `.infobar` to get a smoother effect.

```
.infobar p {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Hope this helps.

here the pen https://codepen.io/crazychukz/pen/VJyOJj

Comment: @ crazychukz  Thanks...for the solution but it doesnot work as per requirement

On hover the infobar should be display over the image but the image and infobar get's pushed up on hover and the infobar must be hidden till the hover or mouseover action is not performed. Attached image above

Comment: @Sid I just updated the answer, hope that's the effect you're trying to achieve.